# Puzzling apparition - RealPlayer rpchrome150browserrecordhelper.dll

Tags: firefox, java, virus, realplayer

I was trying to build and run an application I wrote a long time ago. It was not playing well with the new versions of the open source software it links to. At least two of the open source packages came as precompiled binaries. Norton said they were clean and trusted.

Anyway, my application crashed. Then I noticed something very puzzling in the output-window of the IDE (Visual C++ 2010 Express). It said the application had loaded

```
RealPlayer\BrowserRecordPlugin\Chrome\Hook\rpchrome150browserrecordhelper.dll.
```

My ap is a Windows GUI that has nothing to do with the web, Chrome, or any browser of any kind. I never use Chrome, only Mozilla Firefox.

I did have Java and a RealPlayer plugin running in Firefox. I have since read there was a zero-day exploit discovered last week having to do with Java. I ran a full system scan with Norton. All it found was a few tracking cookies.

So what's up with my simple GUI program loading a browser plugin?

I'm-a shakin.

```
Windows 7, Home Premium, 64bit, Service Pack 1
Mozilla FireFox, latest, was running Java and RealPlayer download plugin
Open Source linked with my ap ---
    wxWidgets binary distribution 2.9.4
    openCV 2.4.2 
    lcms2 2.23 binary
```

Comment: Worse. You have RealPlayer. *runs*

Comment: What does that mean? Joke?